# CSS Styling Pie Chart / Doughnut chart

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, recharts

I'm using Recharts to try to accomplish a doughnut chart with rounded segments, which should end by looking more or less like this:
[image]

This is the closest I can achieve, but as you can see I'm running into some problems:
[image]

First, the first segment is overlapping the others at both edges. I don't know how to correct that despite my searches.
Next, I'm struggling with aligning the legend properly. I found no way to define a width to svg text so long text would go to the next line. (These texts are contained into variables and not hardcoded)

This is my `chart.js`. I cropped some parts to make it simpler, but I'll post the whole thing if needed.

```js
const renderLabelContent = (props) => {
  const { value, title, x, y, midAngle } = props;
  return (
    <g transform={`translate(${x}, ${y})`} textAnchor={'start'}>
      <text x={(midAngle < -90 || midAngle >= 90) ? (0 - (title.length * 3)) : 0} y={0}
        {`${title}`}
      </text>
      <text x={(midAngle < -90 || midAngle >= 90) ? (0 - (title.length * 3)) : 0} y={20}>
        {`${value}`}€
      </text>
    </g>
  );
};
...
export default class Chart extends Component {
...
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="pie-charts">
        <div className="pie-chart-wrapper">
          <PieChart width={400} height={400}>
            <Pie
              stroke="none"
              legendType="circle"
              data={this.state.data}
              dataKey="value"
              startAngle={180}
              endAngle={-180}
              cornerRadius={100}
              innerRadius={60}
              outerRadius={80}
              label={renderLabelContent}
              paddingAngle={-10}
              labelLine={false}
              isAnimationActive={true}
            >
              {
                data.map((entry, index) => (
                  <Cell key={`slice-${index}`} fill={entry.color} />
                ))
              }
              <Label width={50} position="center">
                2,87€
              </Label>
            </Pie>
          </PieChart>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it is better to provide a link to your implementation so people can understand your issue better

Comment: can you provide at least a sample of data, iso we can reproduce the issue in order to help you ?

Comment: I'm receiving an object 
{label: "Logistique partenaire",
price: "0.08",
type: "producer"}
My {title} is my label, and I'm using the type to associate color to my segments. My price is used to determine the length of my segments

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of ways to approach the Labels issue, in recharts you can place a React component on the Label `content` prop, and this could be the way for you to inject your own custom Text component that has a `max-width` and `wrap`, for example:

```
<Label content={<Text warp style={{maxWidth:"50px"}}>long string </Text> } />
```

One more option is to play with the `offset` property of the label, but it is flexible and will impact the overall Label position, for example:

```
  <Label value="Pages of my website" offset={0} position="center" />
```

Comment: I'm having trouble using it correctly. It renders the code into <svg />, and therefore any other balise than text does not work.

Comment: yeah, and it doesn't achieve neither what I want. This just adds a text in the middle of the chart and the offset's not moving it.

Comment: Any chance you can share some code I could play with?